# Android stretch screen to fit bigger screen size

Tags: android, button, size, imageview, screen

How can I enlarge my activity when it is running on bigger screen? I have tried android:scaleType="fitXY" for my imageview but it doesn't work. I have tried plenty of code i researched but none of them work. When I run it on Samsung galaxy S2, it work perfectly. But when I tried it on galaxy note or galaxy S2, the UI is totally different. All imageview are small.

Here's the UI for S2:

[image: S2]

Here's the UI for note and S3:

[image: S3/note]

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageDesc"
        android:src="@drawable/welcome" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFinance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_finance" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHowtouse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_howto" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_settings" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="435dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_about" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make different images and layouts for each resolution.

Use folders for the different image resolution like drawable-hdpi and drawable-xhdpi

I suggest to read here for more details: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I also recommend reading up more about how to actually make layouts for android. It seems that all of your buttons and title bar are pictures. Android is made to handle different screen sizes, up to you to configure your app to do it correctly though.